# Sum of consecutive same values

Tags: r

```
    slope   term
     0.5    1
     0.8    1
     0.3    0
    0.25    0
    0.18    0
     0.4    0
     1.2    1
     3.6    1
     0.67   1
     0.3    0
     0.8    1
     0.4    0
```

I want to know the sum of the slope of each event where 1 and if available consecutive 1 is occuring. So that I get an output like this:

```
slope   term    sum_slope
0.5      1        1.3
0.8      1        1.3
0.3      0        NA
0.25     0        NA
0.18     0        NA
0.4      0        NA
1.2      1       5.47
3.6      1       5.47
0.67     1       5.47
0.3      0        NA
0.8      1       0.8
0.2      0        NA
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to make a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** This uses `rleid` from `data.table` to create the grouping variable and base R for the rest.   `ave` computes the sum of each group and the `ifelse` NAs out the 0 groups.

```
library(data.table)
transform(DF, sum_slope = ave(slope, rleid(term), FUN = sum) * ifelse(term, 1, NA))
```

giving:

```
   slope term sum_slope
1   0.50    1      1.30
2   0.80    1      1.30
3   0.30    0        NA
4   0.25    0        NA
5   0.18    0        NA
6   0.40    0        NA
7   1.20    1      5.47
8   3.60    1      5.47
9   0.67    1      5.47
10  0.30    0        NA
11  0.80    1      0.80
12  0.40    0        NA
```

**2)** This variation of the above uses only base R.  It replaces `rleid` with a base expression, `cumsum(...)`, that does the same.

```
transform(DF, sum_slope = 
  ave(slope, cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(term) != 0)), FUN = sum) * ifelse(term, 1, NA))
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "
 slope   term
     0.5    1
     0.8    1
     0.3    0
    0.25    0
    0.18    0
     0.4    0
     1.2    1
     3.6    1
     0.67   1
     0.3    0
     0.8    1
     0.4    0"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not *exactly* what you want but you can use `data.table::rleid` to group your data - `rleid` is the data.table version of `rle`

Data

```
df <- read.table(text="slope   term
     0.5    1
     0.8    1
     0.3    0
    0.25    0
    0.18    0
     0.4    0
     1.2    1
     3.6    1
     0.67   1
     0.3    0
     0.8    1", header=TRUE)
```

Solution

```
library(data.table)
dt <- setDT(df)
dt[, sum:=sum(slope)*max(term), by=rleid(term)]
dt

    # slope term  sum
 # 1:  0.50    1 1.30
 # 2:  0.80    1 1.30
 # 3:  0.30    0 0.00
 # 4:  0.25    0 0.00
 # 5:  0.18    0 0.00
 # 6:  0.40    0 0.00
 # 7:  1.20    1 5.47
 # 8:  3.60    1 5.47
 # 9:  0.67    1 5.47
# 10:  0.30    0 0.00
# 11:  0.80    1 0.80
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `base R`.  Create a grouping variable using `rle` ('grp'), then with `ave`, grouped by the 'grp', get the `sum` of 'slope' after converting those values that corresponds to 'term' 0 as `NA`

```
grp <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df1$term), values <- seq_along(values)))
df1$sum_slope <-  with(df1, ave(slope * (NA^!term), grp, FUN = sum))
df1$sum_slope
#[1] 1.30 1.30   NA   NA   NA   NA 5.47 5.47 5.47   NA 0.80   NA
```